# spring scheduler - Two Scheduler Beans specified in configuration

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

In my application I had defined a bean for `TaskScheduler` with pool size of 5 as there are multiple `@Scheduled` methods in my application and it was required that they should be able to run in parallel and not on same thread (which is default configuration of Spring Scheduler).

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    return scheduler;
}
```

I was unaware that there already exists a scheduler thread pool like this:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public Executor taskScheduler(MyThreadPoolService myThreadPoolService) {
    return myThreadPoolService.newScheduledThreadPool("Concurrency.Task-Scheduler");//Concurrency.Task-Scheduler is threadpool name.
}
```

Now my application has both the beans but in my logs I notice that the thread running the `@Scheduled` methods is "Concurrency.Task-Scheduler-Thread-1" i.e. the already defined one and all the `@Scheduled` methods are running on the same thread "Concurrency.Task-Scheduler-Thread-1".

I have also noticed that when testing I restart the application again and again, sometimes the `@Scheduled` methods run on different threads as configured in first configuration i.e. different thread names are printed taskScheduler-1, taskScheduler-2 which means the threadpool from my first configuration is being picked up.

I am unable to understand how this is happening. How is it that sometimes "taskScheduler" threadpool is used and sometimes "Concurrency.Task-Scheduler". Shouldn't there be a bean conflict ?

Comment: They have the same name, so in the end, there is only 1 instance of the bean. However which that is remains to be decided as that depends on the order in which the classes are loaded.

Comment: ok , so is it that the bean loading order could be different every time ?

Comment: Yes it can (or at least the processing). If you rename the method you will probably get an exception indicating that you have 2 schedulers.